# GET [...] net::ERR_ABORTED while importing symbol from svg file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vue.js

In my index.html, I am importing a separated html file like this :

```
        <div id="scenarii">
            <scenarii></scenarii>
        </div>
```

The  element is initialized with Vue :

```
let scenarii = new Vue({
    el: "#scenarii",
    template: [ ... stuff .... ],
    components: {scenariiMatrixComponent},

    data: {
        [ ... stuff .... ]
    }
});
```

And in the HTML of my Vue component I am trying to use a svg like this :

```
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <use href="../assets/img/sprites.svg#pen"></use>
                    </svg>
```

And here is my svg file :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
[ ... OTHER SYMBOLS ... ]
    <symbol id="pen" viewBox="-1585.104 -715.999 13.203 13.203">
        <title>Pen</title>
        <g>
            <path d="M3,13.45V16.2H5.75l8.111-8.111-2.75-
2.75ZM15.988,5.962a.73.73,0,0,0,0-1.034L14.272,3.212a.73.73,0,0,0-
1.034,0L11.9,4.554l2.75,2.75,1.342-1.342Z" 
transform="translate(-1588.104 -718.997)"/>
        </g>
    </symbol>
[ ... OTHER SYMBOLS ... ]
 </svg>
```

I am getting the error :

```
GET http://localhost:8081/assets/img/sprites.svg net::ERR_ABORTED
```

The svg file seems OK because I can display the pen image when I am  trying to display it directly from index.html...

Do someone see what's wrong here ?

Comment: `/assets/img/sprites.svg` is this the correct public path on your server?

Comment: yes it is the correct path.

Comment: Does changing the href in the svg work: `<use href="/assets/img/sprites.svg#pen"></use>` ?

Comment: I had already tried it :) I'm still getting the same error....